# How do I link MiKTeX and TeXStudio?

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I am running these applications on my Mac, having installed MiKTeX before TeXStudio. Error message saying "*No LaTeX distribution was found on your system*". I have upgraded  and downloaded all packages on MiKTeX before installing TeXStudio. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Did you install MiKTeX in a different directory than the TeXstudio? this may be the issue 2. Did you add `....\texmfs\install\miktex\bin` to path ? 3. Try restoring the default commands in TeXStudio; `Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Commands > LaTeX`

Comment: Why even run miktex on a Mac when MacTeX is the very easiest LaTeX installation to install by far? Most LaTeX editors expect the latex installation to be MacTeX on a Mac and look in a specific location for it (miktex does not make it self known in that specifik location).

Comment: I am currently running MacTeX (having uninstalled MiKTeX) and it is linked. Thanks for the advice daleif!

Comment: Just remember to update MacTeX afterwards (that is the price of it being so easy to install).

Answer (score 1):

Most LaTeX editors on Mac expects the user to use MacTeX (https://tug.org/mactex/) and uses its settings to look for LaTeX binaries. [1]

Presumably MiKTeX does not setup this special folder and thus the user will have to manually reconfigure the editor/system to suit where MikTeX placed the binaries.

Given how easy it is to install MacTeX, I see no reason to install MikTeX on a Mac.

[1]: MacTeX sets up a special folder which then in turn points to the MacTeX version in use. This was it is easy to switch between two MacTeX versions without having to update settings for the editor.